# Lost branch after cloning the same solution

Tags: git, github

Alright, I will describe my issue as follow:

First, I did a lot of code in my branch (feature-imagetype), added and committed the code while in the branch.

```
git add -A
git commit feature-imagetype -m "blablabla"
```

I wouldn't merge it in my `development` branch yet, because there were still some work to do and I'm not the only developer working in the solution.

But I had problems with `push` and `pull` (publickey rights) when working from home and tried to `clone` the solution again, to see if that solved my problem. And it did!

But when I tried to list my branches, my branch was gone! And of course the code as well.

There fore I would appreciate if someone know how I can get my branch back? Is it even possible after deleting the solution and cloning it again?

Comment: what do you mean "solution"? do you mean local repository or working copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can recover it, unless you can find the copy you deleted in the **recycle bin**.

*If you do though*, restore it somewhere different from the new location then simply copy everything except the `.git` folder from the old to the new directory and then commit it.

Comment: Okay thank you for sharing. I can see that i got the old .git where it is displaying .git\refs\heads\feature-imagetype - Anyway I can get the data somehow?

Comment: @Petey You need the working tree files. It would be hard to recover the commits using the old `.git` folder. Did you find the deleted folder in the recycle bin.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't push your commits to remote repo there is no chance to pull them (or clone) from remote now. You can only try to recover your local repository or working copy.